I became intimate 2 times now i am very sorry an cant face my mother
It is in the title. The first time we did it, i regretted and ask for forgiveness to allah. I had such a hard time facing my mother too.
But last night, i did it again, it was not that intimate it was half intimate but i feel very bad, and i feel like i broke allahs trust more. My moms too. And last time when i was intimate a lot of bad things happened.
And i am scared more now.what will happen. How can i ask for forgiveness from allah for breaking his trust, and also my mothers

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider takin the [tour] and checking our [help].
